how do i normally run "npm-run-algolia"?
When i run npm run algolia cmd, something error come out.
Can someone help me ?
error like this:
Run npm run algolia
  npm run algolia
  shell: /usr/bin/bash -e {0}

> blog-search@1.0.0 algolia
> atomic-algolia

sh: 1: atomic-algolia: Permission denied
Error: Process completed with exit code 126.

https://github.com/ICJJ/Blog/actions/workflows/gh-pages.yml/badge.svg
https://github.com/ICJJ/Blog/actions/workflows/gh-pages.yml
I tried to google and git book,but nothing help got.
I want to normaly run.

Your repo seems to be private, so sharing links to it does not help, we can't see them.

Exit code 126 indicates that atomic-algolia does not have execute permission set
You can fix it by
chmod +x atomic-algolia

